# my datalist keeps showing repeated values even when I use ui.unique

Tags: angularjs, html, unique

I am currently trying to fill a datalist with values from a DB.  I am able to access the DB just fine and fill the datalist but values are repeated when they shouldn't be.  Before when I used a static array for testing purposes, ui.unique worked just fine but now after connecting to the DB the values keep repeating values when it shouldn't.  Below is the code I am using to fill the datalist.  I am unsure why this is happening.

HTML

```
<label for="state" class="col-md-2">State: </label>
        <div class="col-md-2">      
            <input list="stateList" class="form-control input-sm" data-ng-model="agentState" style="width:100px;" onchange="agentDistrict =''">
            <datalist id="stateList">
                <option data-ng-repeat="state in stateDistrictList | unique: 'state'" value="{{state.state}}" >
            </datalist>
        </div>
```

angularjs code

```
function getStatesAndDistricts($http, $scope){
$http.get( apiAccess.getStatesAndDistricts() ).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    var results = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $scope.stateDistrictList[i] = {state : data[i].state, districts : data[i].district };
    }
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      alert("SEARCH ERROR: "+status);
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  The error layed with how I was filling in the array that the datalist values came from.  Instead of using the

```
 "$scope.stateDistrictList[i] = {state : data[i].state, districts : data[i].district };"
```

code to fill in the array, I instead needed to use

```
$scope.stateDistrictList.push({ state: data[i].state, district: data[i].district });
```

After Making this change, my datalists started to properly work and not show repeated values.